# Angular subscribe to multiple asynchronous http calls that partly depend on each other and return arrays

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I'm fairly new to angular and javascript and building my first angular dashboard app that queries the Azure Devops api to get test results:

1. Query the API to get a filtered list of release definitions (about 100)
2. For each release definition get the latest release
3. For each release get a collection of all the test runs from this release.
4. Show a table of all results (each release definition is a row with the test results as expandable table) as soon as the first set of test results are received.

I managed to get this working with nested subscriptions on observables (see below), but I understand this should be avoided and is better done with something likt `mergeMap` / `switchMap` and/or `forkJoin`. Been struggling with that for days, but no luck yet.

And then there's challenge #2: a second stream of data should be added to this: pipelines. Following the same recipe: get a list of pipelines, for each the latest pipeline run, for each of that all the test runs. Both data streams can/should be obtained separately and asynchronously and as soon as one of them has fetched the first set of test runs it can be shown on the dashboard.

How to accomplish this??

My working solution for release definitions only using nested subscriptions:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {   
    this.router.paramMap.pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
    .subscribe(params => {
      this.teamToFilterOn = params.get('team');
      this.apiService.getReleaseDefinitions(this.teamToFilterOn as string)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
      .subscribe((releaseDefinitions: any)=> {
        if (releaseDefinitions.length === 0) {
          this.isLoading = false
        }
        releaseDefinitions.forEach((releaseDefinition: any) => {
          if (releaseDefinition.lastRelease) {
            this.apiService.getRelease(releaseDefinition.lastRelease.id)
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
            .subscribe((info: PipelineOrReleaseInfo) => {
              if (info) {
                this.apiService.getTestRunsByRelease(info.releaseId)
                .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
                .subscribe((testruns: any) => {    
                  this.isLoading = false;              
                  this.results = [...this.results, { info: info, testruns: testruns, totals: this.calculateEnvironmentTotals(testruns.testRunResults)}];             
                  this.dataSource.data = this.results;
                });
              }              
            });
          }
        });            
      });
    });
  }
```

First try using `forkJoin` but stuck on how to proceed. Also not sure if this is correct, because `forkJoin` seems to wait until both observables are complete, but instead as soon as one of them has a result it should proceed to loop over the results and do the remaining calls.

```js
ngOnInit(): void {   
    this.router.paramMap.pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
    .subscribe(params => {
      this.teamToFilterOn = params.get('team');      
      
      let releaseDefQuery =  this.apiService.getReleaseDefinitions(this.teamToFilterOn as string)
      let pipelineDefQuery = this.apiService.getPipelineDefinitions(this.teamToFilterOn as string)

      forkJoin([releaseDefQuery, pipelineDefQuery]).subscribe(definitions => {
        let releaseDefinitions = definitions[0];
        let pipelineDefinitions = definitions[1];

        releaseDefinitions.forEach((releaseDefinition: any) => {
          if (releaseDefinition.lastRelease) {
            this.apiService.getRelease(releaseDefinition.lastRelease.id)
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
            .subscribe((info: PipelineOrReleaseInfo) => {
...
```

**EDIT**: For clarity also added the pipelines flow, resulting in the same objects `info` of type `PipelineOrReleaseInfo` and `testruns`. As soon as one of the flows (releases or pipelines) has these two objects completed it can be shown. So these two flows can/should be merged at some point?

```js
pipelineDefinitions.forEach((pipelineDefinition: any) => {
    this.apiService.getLatestPipelineRun(pipelineDefinition.id)
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
    .subscribe((info: PipelineOrReleaseInfo) => {
      if (info) {
        this.apiService.getTestRunsByPipeline(info.pipelineRunId)
        .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
        .subscribe((testruns: any) => {    
          this.isLoading = false;              
          this.results = [...this.results, { info: info, testruns: testruns, totals: this.calculateEnvironmentTotals(testruns.testRunResults)}];             
          this.dataSource.data = this.results;
        });
      }              
    });
}
```

**EDIT**: fully working code from accepted answer:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.teamToFilterOn = this.router.snapshot.paramMap.get('team');    

    const releaseResults$: Observable<any> = this.apiService.getReleaseDefinitions(this.teamToFilterOn as string).pipe(
      mergeMap(releaseDefs => releaseDefs), // Turns Observable<[]> into Observable<>
      filter((releaseDef: any) => releaseDef.lastRelease), // Take only releaseDefs with a lastRelease
      mergeMap((releaseDef: any) => this.apiService.getRelease(releaseDef.lastRelease.id)),
      filter(releaseInfo => !!releaseInfo), // Continue only when release info is returned
      mergeMap((releaseInfo: PipelineOrReleaseInfo) => this.apiService.getTestRunsByRelease(releaseInfo.releaseId)
      .pipe(map(testruns => ({ testruns, info: releaseInfo }))))
    );

    const pipelineResults$: Observable<any> = this.apiService.getPipelineDefinitions(this.teamToFilterOn as string).pipe(
      mergeMap(pipelineDefs => pipelineDefs), // Turns Observable<[]> into Observable<def>
      mergeMap((pipelineDef: any) => this.apiService.getLastPipelineRun(pipelineDef.id)),
      filter(pipelineInfo => !!pipelineInfo), // Continue only when pipeline info is returned
      mergeMap((pipelineInfo: PipelineOrReleaseInfo) => this.apiService.getTestRunsByPipeline(pipelineInfo.pipelineRunId)
      .pipe(map(testruns => ({ testruns, info: pipelineInfo }))))
    );
   
    merge(releaseResults$, pipelineResults$)
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
    .subscribe(({ testruns, info }) => {
      this.isLoading = false;              
      this.results = [...this.results, { info: info, testruns: testruns, totals: this.calculateEnvironmentTotals(testruns.testRunResults)}];             
      this.dataSource.data = this.results;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like any kind of `Stream` (e.g. `Promise`s), when you see nesting in `Observable`s you might want to take a step back to see if it's really warranted.

Let's examine your solution bit by bit.

Our starting point is:

```
this.router.paramMap.pipe(takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe))
```

Then you subscribe, but within that subscribe you do observable operations on the given data, this strongly suggests you should be `pipe`ing an operation instead, and then subscribe on the final result.

In this case you want to `map` your `params` to some `Observable`. You also might benefit from the "interrupt early" behavior that [`switchMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/switchMap) offers. Otherwise there's also [`mergeMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/mergeMap) as a potential option if you don't want to "interrupt early" (it used to be more appropriately named [`flatMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/const/flatMap)).

We'll add a [`filter`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/filter) and [`map`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/map) for good measure, to ensure we have the `team` param, and to pluck it out (since we don't need the rest).

```
this.router.paramMap.pipe(
    takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe),
    filter(params => params.has("team"))
    map(params => params.get("team"))
    switchMap(team => {
      this.teamToFilterOn = team as string;
      // We'll dissect the rest
    })
) // [...]
```

Then comes the part with what you want to do with that team.

You have multiple "tasks" that rely on the same input, and you want them both at the same time, so reaching for [`forkJoin`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/forkJoin) is a good call. But there's also [`combineLatest`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/combineLatest) that does something similar, but combine the results "step by step" instead.

You use the word "latest" for both your tasks, so we'll indeed reach for `combineLatest` instead:

```
const releaseDef$ = // [...]
const pipelineDef$ = // [...]
return combineLatest([releaseDef$, pipelineDef$]);
```

Now let's dissect these two operations.

From what I gather, you're only interested in releases that have a `lastRelease`. You also don't want to "switch" when a new one comes in, you want them all, let's encode that:

```
const releaseDef$ = this.apiService.getReleaseDefinitions(this.teamToFilterOn as string).pipe(
    mergeMap(releaseDefs => releaseDefs), // Turns Observable<def[]> into Observable<def>
    filter(releaseDef => releaseDef.lastRelease),
    mergeMap(lastReleaseDef => this.apiService.getRelease(releaseDefinition.lastRelease.id)),
    filter(info => !!info)
    mergeMap(info => this.apiService.getTestRunsByRelease(info.releaseId).pipe(map(testruns => ({ testruns, info }))),
)
```

You'll notice I also pipe into the result of `getTestRunsByRelease`. That is because unlike `Promise`s, we don't have an alternative syntax like `async/await` that help with keeping previous state in an easy way. Instead we have to rely on the monoid operation `map` from within our monad operation `flatMap` and drag the previous results along. For `Promise`s, both `map` and `flatMap` are `.then`. For `Observable`s they are respectively `map` and `mergeMap`.

We apply a very similar transformation to your pipelines:

```
const pipelineDef$ = this.apiService.getPipelineDefinitions(this.teamToFilterOn as string)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(pipelineDefs => pipelineDefs), // Turns Observable<def[]> into Observable<def>
    mergeMap(pipelineDef => this.apiService.getLatestPipelineRun(pipelineDef.id)),
    filter(info => !!info),
    mergeMap(info => this.apiService.getTestRunsByPipeline(info.pipelineRunId).pipe(map(testruns => ({ testruns, info }))),
  );
```

Here if you need to operate independently on the results of `releaseDef$` and `pipelineDef$` you can use [`tap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/tap).

Note that these could easily be extracted into two methods.

As the end operation is the same for both, and their results have the same shape, you can use [`merge`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/merge) instead of `combineLatest` to merge the two observables into one that emits all values of both as they come in (instead of combining and emitting the latest value of each in an array):

```
return merge(releaseDef$, pipelineDef$);
```

To wrap this up, let's put it all together:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.router.paramMap.pipe(
    takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe),
    filter(params => params.has("team"))
    map(params => params.get("team"))
    switchMap(team => {
      this.teamToFilterOn = team as string;
      
      const releaseDef$ = this.apiService.getReleaseDefinitions(this.teamToFilterOn as string).pipe(
        mergeMap(releaseDefs => releaseDefs), // Turns Observable<def[]> into Observable<def>
        filter(releaseDef => releaseDef.lastRelease),
        mergeMap(lastReleaseDef => this.apiService.getRelease(releaseDefinition.lastRelease.id)),
        filter(info => !!info)
        mergeMap(info => this.apiService.getTestRunsByRelease(info.releaseId).pipe(map(testruns => ({ testruns, infos })))),
      );

      const pipelineDef$ = this.apiService.getPipelineDefinitions(this.teamToFilterOn as string)
        .pipe(
          mergeMap(pipelineDefs => pipelineDefs), // Turns Observable<def[]> into Observable<def>
          mergeMap(pipelineDef => this.apiService.getLatestPipelineRun(pipelineDef.id)),
          filter(info => !!info),
          mergeMap(info => this.apiService.getTestRunsByPipeline(info.pipelineRunId).pipe(map(testruns => ({ testruns, info }))),
        )

      return merge(releaseDef$, pipelineDef$);
    })
  ).subscribe(({ testruns, infos }) => {
    this.isLoading = false;              
    this.results = [...this.results, { info: info, testruns: testruns, totals: this.calculateEnvironmentTotals(testruns.testRunResults)}];             
    this.dataSource.data = this.results;
  });
}
```

You'll notice I only used on `takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)` as the "main" observable chain will stop with that, which means operation will stop as well.

If you're unsure or encounter issues, you can still sprinkle them as the very first argument of each `.pipe`.

Comment: Thanks for your lightning fast reply and step-by-step breakdown. Makes it easier to understand what's happening. I guess I don't need the tap because the releases and pipelines stream both return the same objects: `info` (of type `PipelineOrReleaseInfo`) and `testruns`. The two streams can be kind of merged and as soon as either of them has the testruns completed it can be shown. How can this be done? And another question: I need the intermediate result (in this case `info`) also in the end result, but now it's not available due to the piping?

Comment: I added the pipelines flow in the original post for clarity

Comment: I completely forgot about keeping `info`, I'll edit it in

Comment: @jvanderwoude As I understand it, there's some operations that are different between the two (so their respective piping), but the end operation is the same for both? I'm editing my answer to take that into account

Comment: Thanks again! Been struggling for this some time now, so again call for help. Guess I have to learn a lot.. The first calls are getting executed, an array of releasedefinitions is returned and also an array of pipelines. But then nothing. `getLatestPipelineRun` is failing because the id is undefined and also the `getRelease()` seems not to be executed at all for all definitions. Am I missing something? Does `mergeMap` perform a foreach kind of thing by itself or should I add it?

Comment: Ooooh it returns an array, my bad. Basically chain/pipe `mergeMap(identity)` or `mergeMap(x => x)` to anything that returns an array and it'll be good. I'm editing the answer to add that

Comment: And it's finally working! Thanks a million @Vivick. I will post the working code as soon everything's cleaned up a bit.

Answer (score 0):

#### How to conditionally merge multiple observable list using switchMap

```
$data = this.catService.get().pipe(
    switchMap((cats) => {
      return this.nestService.get().pipe(
        map((nests) => {
          return cats.map((cat) => {
            return {
              ...cat,
              nest: nests.find((nest) => (nest.catid = cat.id)),
            };
          });
        })
      );
    })
  );
```